# How should I understand the participle phrase ''found useful''?

Tags: verbs, phrasal-verbs

In this following context, should I take this sentence as: '' ....are found useful merely terms in conventional... ''?

Does the phrase ''found useful'' modify the word ''terms''?
Please, simplify this to me...

Thanks to All...

Context:

> 'The words “I,” “you,” “he,” etc., are merely terms found useful in
> conventional or current (vohåra) speech, but do not designate
> realities''

Source: P. 7

Fundamentals of Buddhism

by Nyanatiloka mahathera

Comment: You really do have to stop reading this stuff. Existentialism is not an easy topic anyway; more impenetrable still when translated in such a 'wordy' manner.

Comment: They are terms **which are** found [to be] useful.

Comment: The missing word is “that”: “…are merely terms **that** are found useful…”.   This sentence demonstrates two things: first, that it is permitted in English to delete the word “that” when it introduces a relative clause; and second, writers should think twice before doing so, unless they _want_ to produce dense, unfriendly writing.

Comment: @KrisW Actually, two words are "missing": "that are" (or perhaps "which are"). This is called "whiz-deletion".

Comment: @MarcInManhattan yes, you’re correct. “that are” is the deletion.  It shouldn’t be “which”, because which-clauses are supposed to be set off by a comma.

Answer (score 0):

It may be clearer if we expand the phrasing, by adding "which" or "that":

> The words “I,” “you,” “he,” etc., are terms **that are** found **to be** useful in conventional or current (vohåra) speech, but do not designate realities'

or

> The words “I,” “you,” “he,” etc., are terms **which are** found **to be** useful in conventional or current (vohåra) speech, but do not designate realities'

Also, modifying the word choice:

> The words “I,” “you,” “he,” etc., are terms **which are** *considered (or regarded)* **to be** useful in conventional or current (vohåra) speech, but do not designate realities'

Comment: Saying "Words have been omitted" makes it sound as if the sentence is somehow improper or incomplete. **Nothing has been omitted** but the meaning is the same as the longer sentences you give.

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: @ColinFine, just wondering, if this phenomenon is referred to as "whiz deletion", you would say **nothing has been deleted**. So calling it "whiz deletion" is wrong.

Comment: you're confusing the name with the substance. _Whiz deletion_ is indeed a name name used for the relationship between these two structures. That doesn't mean that there is actually anything deleted anywhere in the process of speaking or writing the sentence.